# Remove time part from a DateTime

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a bunch of data in a Google Spreadsheet and I have a column of Date's that are formatted like this:

> 2017-04-09T08:38:15Z

I want to remove everything after the date so in this case it will leave the following:

> 2017-04-09

I want to use a the "Search using regular expressions" feature for "Find and Replace..." in Google Sheets to do this, can anyone please help me with such a regular expression that is able to be used as a simple search and replace?

Comment: Have you tried any patterns yet?

Comment: Which tool do you want to use? Sed, awk, perl, ... What have you tried? In which way did your own code not achieve what you want?

Comment: Please explain the requirements for the regex. In your case, are you after matching the date, and keeping it while removing all the rest?

Comment: Why the downvote? I have no idea how to use regular expressions, I did it my own way that wasn't very efficient and believe me it will help no one if I post that, so I am asking for a better solution and this might help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
```

it will match

- `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `-`
- `\d{2}`
- `-`
- `\d{2}`

and return pattern `DDDD-DD-DD`,

**EDIT.** for find and replace you need to replace the rest of text. Try this regex:

`T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z`

Comment: Thanks, that is a nice solution if I wanted to create another column for a result of the date string. But I really want to be able to "Find and Replace..." feature using "Search using regular expressions". Any ideas?

Comment: I've made an edit with a suggestion. Need to have your sample data to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not build another column that uses the datetime but formats it as string the way you want, then copy/"paste values" that derived column back on top of you original column?

Comment: Thanks. I actually found a solution in the end, but I really want to be using Regular Expressions more as they are very handy

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regular expression,

`/(\d+\-\d+\-\d+)/g`

Comment: Thanks but this gives me "There are no entries matching /(\d+\-\d+\-\d+)/g"

Comment: @jakedunc  can you share the code where you use the regex?

Comment: Sorry it is not in code. I am trying to use the "Search using regular expressions" option on "Find and Replace..." in a Google Sheets document